# Sequelize foreign key formats

Tags: sequelize.js

Assuming I have Users and Messages tables in a database, is this the preferred way to establish a foreign key?  What are some alternatives?

```
Users.hasMany(Messages, {
  foreignKey: {name: 'user_id', allowNull: false }, 
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```